# Como hacer una grafica a partir de un agrupamiento en Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Soy nuevo en Pandas y sobre todo en **Matplotlib**. Realice el siguiente agrupamiento de un dataframe(df) y lo guarde en un nuevo dataframe llamado **'sexoDepartamento'**, ahora quiero realizar un grafico de barras de columnas apiladas donde la barra describa la cantidad de M y F (columna Sexo) por departamento.

```
sexoDepartamento = df.groupby(['Departamento', 'Sexo']).agg({
   'Sexo': 'count'
})

sexoDepartamento.head(10)
```

Este es el resultado de mi codigo, lo cual esta bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene cuando quiero hacer un grafico parecido a este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad no tengo idea de como pueda hacer este grafico con los datos de sexoDepartamento, agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()

sexoDepartamento.plot(kind="bar", stacked = True)
plt.show()
```

Pero me aparece la grafica de así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías poner el error y el código que lo genera? tal vez solo tengas problemas por los multi índices

Comment: Ya agregue el código con el que estoy intentando generar la grafica. @Christian

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama [bar stacked](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html)